# Ionic 7 with Angular 16 standalone, HttpClientModule not working in production build on Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

My application works fine in the browser, but when I build it with the --prod flag, my application no longer works (API requests and translation are not working fine).

I have added the following in my main.ts file:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    importProvidersFrom(IonicModule.forRoot({ mode: 'ios', backButtonText: ''})),
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    importProvidersFrom(TranslateModule.forRoot(
      {
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
      }
    )),
    importProvidersFrom(AngularTokenModule.forRoot({ 
        apiBase: API_URL,
        oAuthPaths: {
          facebook: '/auth/facebook'
        }
      }
    )),
    importProvidersFrom(SortablejsModule.forRoot({ animation: 150 })),
    importProvidersFrom(InAppPurchase2),
    importProvidersFrom(Calendar),
    provideRouter(routes),
  ],
})
```

On the device, the error message is:
**"ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).reduceRight is not a function."**

Replacing `importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule)` with `provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())` works in the browser but not in production.

on angular.json i have:

```
"aot": true,
"buildOptimizer": true,
```